# Mass-assignement error in fields_for form using Devise user with multiple roles

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, nested-forms, mass-assignment

I looked on plenty of issues related to mass-assignement in nested attributes but none of them helped me out...

I am using Devise and have one `User` model with different types, as the `Client` one:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :email, :name, :password, :password_confirmation, :remember_me, :rolable_type
  belongs_to :rolable, :polymorphic => true
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :rolable
end

class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :user, :as => :rolable
  attr_accessible :specialty, :address
end
```

I have the following form for creating a new user with the client type and client attributes and which is working:

```
[...]

  resource.rolable = child_class_name.constantize.new if resource.rolable.nil?

<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>

[...]

  <% # customized code begin %>
  <%= fields_for resource.rolable do |rf| %>
    <% if rolable_type == 'client' %>

    <div><%= rf.label :specialty %><br />
    <%= rf.text_field :specialty %></div>

[...]

    <% end %>
  <% end %>

  <%= hidden_field :user, :rolable_type, :value => rolable_type %>
  <% # customized code end %>

[...]

  <div><%= f.submit "Sign up" %></div>
<% end %>
```

I have the following for editing the same user and which is not working: I am getting the following error : `ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in UsersController#update` : `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: client`

```
    <%= form_for(@user) do |f| %>
       <%= render 'shared/error_messages', object: f.object %>

[...]

      <% f.fields_for(@user.rolable) do |rf| -%>

        <div><%= rf.label :specialty %><br />
        <%= rf.text_field :specialty %></div>

        <div><%= rf.label :address %><br />
        <%= rf.text_field :address %></div>
      <% end %>

[...]
```

Here is my `UsersController`update action:

```
  def update
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    if @user.update_attributes(params[:user])
      flash[:success] = "Profile updated"
      sign_in @user
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'edit'
    end
  end
```

Comment: the weirdest thing is that I still run into a `mass-assignement error` even when I set `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = false`....

Answer (score 0):

you need an accepts_nested_attributes_for :rolable in User class

See: [Rails 3.1: accepts_nested_attributes_for and has_one association - won't work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693929/rails-3-1-accepts-nested-attributes-for-and-has-one-association-wont-work)

Comment: I run now into a mass-assignement error whereas I added `accepts_nested_attributes_for :rolable` in `User` class : `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: client` (thank you for your help!)

Comment: try changing it to accepts_nested_attributes_for :client and i think you need to add :client to your attr_accessible list

Answer (score 0):

*Solution by OP.*

I changed `<% f.fields_for(@user.rolable) do |rf| %>` for `<%= f.fields_for :rolable do |rf| %>`.

And it worked